# Поиск записей в MySQL по подстроке

Tags: mysql, sql

проблема следующая:
в БД хранится строка **"тестовая строка"**,
на вдох в запросе передается эта же строка, но модифицированная, вида **"uuid: тестовая строка"**

модифицированная строка больше чем исходная, поэтому оператор LIKE мне не помог (либо я неправильно его использовал)

Возможно ли найти исходную строку **"тестовая строка"** по модифицированной **"uuid: тестовая строка"**?

Comment: Отрезать "модифицированной" строке паразитное начало и сравнивать. Делов-то...

Comment: Ну или идиотский вариант `WHERE 'uuid: тестовая строка' LIKE CONCAT('%', column)` с полным tablescan.

Comment: @Akina спасибо большое, мне отлично подходит вариант с полным сканированием таблицы, поскольку в выборке участвует еще одно поле, по которому проставлен индекс, получается небольшое количество записей и запрос отрабатывает быстро